# how to set the navigation bar symbles don't change line when catch next subsection in beamer

Tags: beamer, templates, navigation

i'm using theme Berlin,and the navigation bar symbles change a line when i use the \subsection 
such that
[image]

in the northwest corner,the circles present in 3 lines
but how can i let them in a single line like this
[image]
i don't want to change the theme,can i do that while using berlin ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `compress` class option:

| wihout `compress` | with `compress` |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |

---

Some background information from the `beamer` manual (from section 8.2.3 Navigation Bars):

> `\documentclass[compress]{beamer}`
>
> Tries to make all navigation bars as small as possible. For example,
> all small frame representations in the navigation bars for a single
> section are shown alongside each other. Normally, the representations
> for different subsections are shown in different lines. Furthermore,
> section and subsection navigations are compressed into one line.

---

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\begin{frame}{frametitle}contents\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{frametitle}contents\end{frame}
\subsection{subsection}
\begin{frame}{frametitle}contents\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{frametitle}contents\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{frametitle}contents\end{frame}
\subsection{subsection}
\begin{frame}{frametitle}contents\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{frametitle}contents\end{frame}

\section{section}
\begin{frame}{frametitle}contents\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks,that perfectly soving my problem.